# Outlook headers showing in Gibberish

Tags: php, mysql, email, character-encoding

I am working on a disposable mail service..

English works great always.. I fixed the encoding issues and now whenever a mail gets sent from a webmail service in whatever language it displays correct (used UTF-8 Encoding).

The only problem is that whenever a mail gets sent from MS Outlook , in languages other than english, it show weird headers:

> Subject: Ù„ÙˆØ­Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙØ§ØªÙŠØ­ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©

OR

> Subject: ×¢×›×©×™×•
>    ×œ×™ ×–×” ×œ× ×¢×•×‘

The Message is displayed like this:

> ����� ����

I tried encoding this but it doesn't work.
I'm sure it has something to do with MySQL because the webmail client displays it correctly.

Thank you

Comment: are you using any HTML in the mailout body? Showing your codes may help.

Comment: Outlook has a specific template that probably messes things up..
My site only receives the emails.. I use imap_open to retrieve the mails from the server and then add them to the DB.. If a mail comes from anywhere else than outlook it goes in the DB and gets encoded.. It only doesn't work from Outlook

Comment: I don't use or code for Outlook, so I don't think I could help to troubleshoot your problem. Have you Google'd with any success, or here on SO with someone having the same or similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run the foreign text through something like php's htmlentities and htmlspecialchars to convert the accentuated and non-html characters to ascii html codes instead.

```
$subject = "especificações";
$subject = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($subject), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
var_dump($subject);
// returns string(36) "especifica&ccedil;&otilde;es"
```